# How to Call Function from Fortran DLL in delphi?

Tags: delphi, dll, fortran

I have problem with delphi code. I want to call the function in delphi to process the fortran function, but I have  transferred to DLL. Here is code Fortran

```
    SUBROUTINE c_zsn(m,d,k,f,zsn,nf)

    ! Specify that the routine name is to be made available to callers of the
    ! DLL and that the external name should not have any prefix or suffix

    !MS$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: c_zsn
    !MS$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'c_zsn' :: c_zsn
    !MS$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: m,d,k,nf
    !MS$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: f,zsn
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER :: nf,i
    REAL(KIND(0.D0)) :: m,d,k,f(0:(nf-1)),zsn(0:(nf-1)),om,pi
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.D0)) :: j

    j = (0.d0, 1.d0)
    pi = 4.d0 * datan(1.d0)

    do i=0,nf-1
    om = 2.d0*pi*f(i)
    zsn(i) = abs(-om**2*m-j*om*d+k)
    end do

    END SUBROUTINE
```

and here is code for the Delphi that I used

```
    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    type tarray=array[0..10]of double;
    var a:thandle;
        fcn:function(s,d,f:double;var g,h:tarray;n:integer):double;
        e,f,d,g,h,i,j:double;
        k:tarray;
        l,o:tarray;
        n,m:integer;
    begin
      a:=LoadLibrary('dllsub.dll');
      if (A=0) then
      begin
        Application.MessageBox('Failed to open library','Error', MB_OK or MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        exit;
      end;
      @fcn:=GetProcAddress(a, 'c_zsn');
      if @b=nil then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Failed to open function');
        exit;
      end;

      e:=2;
      f:=200;
      d:=0.01;
      n:=10;
      for m:=0 to n do
      l[m]:=m;

      fcn(e,d,f,l,o,n);      // this is the problem

      FreeLibrary(a);
    end;
```

I cannot call the function (the bold one).

Comment: C is "lingua franca" of DLLs. I think there are a lot of tutorials hwo to make C header file (*.h) for your Fortran file. Then there are a lot of tutorials how to translate C headers to Pascal.

Comment: @Arioch'The No need to convert interface to C.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan of course direct translation always can make better results than using intermediate "lingua franca". But the latter sometimes is "good enough" and there are more offerings :-) It is just a case of "Divide and conquer" in a sense

Comment: @fcn:=GetProcAddress(a, 'c_zsn'), but then testing if @b=nil ???

Answer (score 1):

I would declare the function like this:

```
procedure c_zsn(
  m: Double;
  d: Double;
  k: double; 
  f: PDouble; 
  zsn: PDouble;
  n: Integer
); stdcall; external 'dllsub.dll';
```

You do need to specify the calling convention. You omitted that which meant that your code used the default `register` calling convention which is private to Delphi. I'm guessing that the calling convention is `stdcall` but it may be `cdecl`. Check the compiler documentation to be sure.

And it is not at all obvious to me why you declared a function that returns a double. The Fortran does not do that.

Other than that I changed the parameter names to match the Fortran code. I also switched to load time linking which is easier to code against. You can skip the calls to `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` and let the loader resolve the linkage.

Finally, I think the two arrays are better passed as `PDouble` (that is pointer to `Double`) rather than committing at compile time to fixed size arrays.

You can call the function like this:

```
c_zsn(e,d,f,@l[0],@o[0],n);
```

Do note that you have declared arrays of length 11 rather than length 10. Did you mean to do that? I think you should declare the arrays like this:

```
var
  l, o: array [0..9] of Double;
```

One final point is that the Fortran code is very simple. It would be very easy indeed to translate it into Delphi.